# BufferedReader.readLine() do not read and hang the system(wait)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, stream, filestream, bufferedreader

`BufferedReader.readLine()` do not read and hang the `system(wait)`.

```
InputStream istrm = runtimeProcess.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader istrmrdr = new InputStreamReader(istrm);
BufferedReader buffrdr = new BufferedReader(istrmrdr);
System.out.println("4");
String data;
String st;
System.out.println("4a");
while (!(st=buffrdr.readLine()).isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("5 in loop");
}
```

Comment: Well presumably you're not giving it a line to read... it's hard to say any more without more information. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: should i post my full Method ?

Comment: No, you should tell us why you expect it to be able to read a line. What process are you reading from? Is it possibly blocking because you're not reading from the error stream?

Comment: i am trying to import MYSQL database runtimeProcess = new ProcessBuilder(executeCmd).start();

Comment: Does that command normally require user input? Is it perhaps writing to the error instead of the output stream?

Comment: it is importing .sql file to the system, sorry i m new in java could not properly understand the 2nd part of your comment , i posted my question again with more detail can you check that plz?

Comment: Please don't post multiple questions on the same topic - *edit* your question with more information.

Comment: sorry i dont know that editing stuff earlier, i will b careful next time

Answer (score 2):

You need to continually read from the processes input stream to ensure that it doesn't block.

Read this : http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: This assisted a lot but still did not discuss timeouts :(

Answer (score 0):

The point is this line

```
while (!(st=buffrdr.readLine()).isEmpty())
```

Your code will wait for the line to terminate. That is, till it finds "\n" character; It will keep buffering and hence will not come out of loop. So either in the input stream manage to have quick lines. Or read through bytes. 
You should probably read bytes and work along.

```
int i=0;
char[] buf = new char[10000]
while((i=buffrdr.read(buf,i,100))!= -1)
{
 String h = new String(buf);
 //use h o print accordingly.
```

Comment: i m still facing the waiting issue with bytes reading whats the problem could be

Comment: try this:
while((i = buffrdr.read())!=-1){//}