# BufferedReader.readLine() do not read and hang the system

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, streaming, buffer, bufferedreader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BufferedReader.readLine() do not read and hang the system(wait)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339424/bufferedreader-readline-do-not-read-and-hang-the-systemwait)

Trying to import MYSQL Database, but facing problem in  BufferedReader.readLine() Methode it make system waiting for something.
Code do import database backup after some time, but system always run and readLine method do not allow system to move forward, and in this code the output come.
1
2
3
4
4a
and system starts waiting for something.
Any Solution 
Thanks In Advance

```
public static boolean restoreDB(String dbName, String dbUserName, String dbPassword, String source) {
    String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysql", "--user=" + dbUserName, "--password=" + dbPassword, "-e", "source \"D:/khokher/medmax.sql\""};

    System.out.println("1 Processing Start");
    Process runtimeProcess = null;
    try {
        String line = "";
        System.out.println("2");

        runtimeProcess = new ProcessBuilder(executeCmd).start();
        System.out.println("3");

        InputStream istrm = runtimeProcess.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader istrmrdr = new InputStreamReader(istrm);
        BufferedReader buffrdr = new BufferedReader(istrmrdr);
        System.out.println("4");
        String data;
        String st;
        System.out.println("4a");
        while (!(st=buffrdr.readLine()).isEmpty()) { // actual problem is in readLine Method it block system
        System.out.println("5 in loop");
        }

        int ev = 0 ;
        System.out.println("7 .waitFor()");
        if (runtimeProcess.waitFor() != 0) {
        ev = runtimeProcess.exitValue();
        System.out.println("8 process exitValue()");
        }else{
            System.out.println("9 Backup restored successfully");
            return true;
        }



    } catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("10");
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        return false;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("11");
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        return false;
    } finally { 
        System.out.println("processing stoped");
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Does the program produce any output? Does your code continue once the program has completed?

Comment: it produce only 1 2 3 4 and 4a in above code and do not go into the loop to print 5 in loop and neither it come down to print 7 and no exeption came also

Comment: So in other words the process produces no output at all, but I don't see how that justifies you re-posting the same question within 15 minutes.

Comment: i m new to stackoverflow i was not aware of editing my old question sorry to everone, but thing is my problem is not yet over

Comment: @ShahjahanKhokhar Yes it is. See my answer and my final comment under it.

Comment: let me try your suggestions i hope i can fix it.

Answer (score 3):

[`buffrdr.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) returns null when EOF

`while (!(st=buffrdr.readLine()).isEmpty())` will throw a NPE

if you want to stop reading after the first empty line you have to do:

```
while ((( st = buffrdr.readLine()) != null)  && ( ! st.trim().isEmpty()))
```

If no Exception is thrown, the program never stop because the process `runtimeProcess` never terminates and never output an empty line.

You should read the error stream of `runtimeProcess`, because it may saturate the stream, hanging the process (as shown by EJP).

Comment: but my program is not throwing any exception at all

Answer (score 1):

@Aubin is entirely correct to point out the NPE, but if readLine() blocks, there is no data available; in other words, the sender isn't sending. That could be because you haven't closed the stdin of the process you are executing. It could also be because you aren't reading the error stream. Interrupting your own thread is also pretty pointless.

Comment: +1: You're right, the err stream may be saturated, blocking the underlying process, hanging its client.

Comment: i m interrupting it in case of any exception but there is no exception in this code it simply keep waiting and the main purpose is to import the database which is done beautifully means data is available in any sense but it is waiting on readLine() , and could you explain how should i close me stdin i dont know this thing

Comment: @ShahjahanKhokhar Interrupting the current thread is completely pointless unless you are calling Thread.isInterrupted() somewhere, which you aren't. You need to read the answer you were given about traps when executing processes in your original thread, instead of wasting everybody's time re-posting the same question.